# Checking for collision

Tags: c++, allegro5

I'm coding a game for our final project in our major using Allegro but I get some issues with collision. My game is basically Battleships and what I did is after a loading screen, a screen will appear wherein you can select the coordinates of your ships using the arrow keys and lock it with space bar. And if the coordinates you chose is already occupied the space bar doesn't work.

My problem is that I can't check the ships' length and width for collision before placing. The ships length and width is only considered when you've already placed the ship and the next ship can overlap with the other ships. I've tried everything but I get some issues. And not just that but some part of the grid cannot be chosen as well even though it's empty.

```
void shipplacement(){

 //something like a cursor for ship placement
 shipx = 0;
 shipy = 0;

 while(!placed)
 {
 ALLEGRO_EVENT ev;
 al_wait_for_event(prepqueue, &ev);

  if(ev.type == ALLEGRO_EVENT_KEY_DOWN) {
     switch(ev.keyboard.keycode) {
        case ALLEGRO_KEY_UP:
           key[KEY_UP] = true;
           break;

        case ALLEGRO_KEY_DOWN:
           key[KEY_DOWN] = true;
           break;

        case ALLEGRO_KEY_LEFT: 
           key[KEY_LEFT] = true;
           break;

        case ALLEGRO_KEY_RIGHT:
           key[KEY_RIGHT] = true;
           break;

        case ALLEGRO_KEY_SPACE:
        xcheck();  // checks the coordinates of the ship controlled
        tst();     // checks for collision and if space bar should work
           break;
     }
  }

  else if(ev.type == ALLEGRO_EVENT_KEY_UP) {
     switch(ev.keyboard.keycode) {
        case ALLEGRO_KEY_UP:
           key[KEY_UP] = false;
           break;

        case ALLEGRO_KEY_DOWN:
           key[KEY_DOWN] = false;
           break;

        case ALLEGRO_KEY_LEFT: 
           key[KEY_LEFT] = false;
           break;

        case ALLEGRO_KEY_RIGHT:
           key[KEY_RIGHT] = false;
           break;
           }
           } 

 if(redraw && al_is_event_queue_empty(prepqueue)){
      if (shippl[1]){
         //redraw the background and draw the "selector"
         }
      else if (shippl[2]){
        //redraw the background and draw the new "selector" and the placed ship.
         }
      else if (shippl[3]){
         //redraw the background and draw the new "selector" and the placed ships.
         }
      else if (shippl[4]){
         //redraw the background and draw the new "selector" and the placed ships.
         }
      else if (shippl[5]){
        //redraw the background and draw the new "selector" and the placed ships.
         }
 redraw = false;
 al_flip_display();}
    }   
}      

void tst(){
       if(logic == 0){
                                             makeittrue();
                                             shippl[count] = false;
                                             shipfx[count] = shipx;
                                             shipfy[count] = shipy;
                                             count++;
                                             logic++;
                                             shipx = 0;
                                             shipy = 0;
                                             }

        else if(logic == 1){
                    if(!s1[xholder][yholder] && !s1[xholder][y2] && !s1[xholder][y3] && !s1[xholder][y4]){
                                              makeittrue();
                                             shippl[count] = false;
                                             shipfx[count] = shipx;
                                             shipfy[count] = shipy;
                                             count++;
                                             logic++;
                                             shipx = 0;
                                             shipy = 0;
                                             }
                    }
        else if(logic == 2){
                    if(!s2[xholder][yholder] && !s2[xholder][y2] && !s2[xholder][y3] && !s1[xholder][yholder] && !s1[xholder][y2] && !s1[xholder][y3] && !s1[xholder][y4]){
                                              makeittrue();
                                             shippl[count] = false;
                                             shipfx[count] = shipx;
                                             shipfy[count] = shipy;
                                             count++;
                                             logic++;
                                             shipx = 0;
                                             shipy = 0;
                                             }
                    }
        else if(logic == 3){
                    if(!s3[xholder][yholder] && !s3[x2][yholder] && !s3[x3][yholder] && !s2[xholder][yholder] && !s2[xholder][y2] && !s2[xholder][y3] && !s1[xholder][yholder] && !s1[xholder][y2] && !s1[xholder][y3] && !s1[xholder][y4]){
                                              makeittrue();
                                             shippl[count] = false;
                                             shipfx[count] = shipx;
                                             shipfy[count] = shipy;
                                             count++;
                                             logic++;
                                             shipx = 0;
                                             shipy = 0;
                                             }
                    }
        else if(logic == 4){
                    if(!s4[xholder][yholder] && !s4[xholder][y2] && !s3[xholder][yholder] && !s3[x2][yholder] && !s3[x3][yholder] && !s2[xholder][yholder] && !s2[xholder][y2] && !s2[xholder][y3] && !s1[xholder][yholder] && !s1[xholder][y2] && !s1[xholder][y3] && !s1[xholder][y4]){
                                              makeittrue();
                                             shippl[count] = false;
                                             shipfx[count] = shipx;
                                             shipfy[count] = shipy;
                                             count++;
                                             logic++;
                                             shipx = 0;
                                             shipy = 0;
                                             }
                    }
        }


void makeittrue(){
      // s1 is ship1 with length of 4 blocks
      // s2 is ship2 with length of 3 blocks
      // s3 is ship3 with width of 3 blocks
      // s4 is ship4 with length of 2 blocks
      // s5 is ship5 with width of 2 blocks
      if(count == 1){
               y2 = yholder + 1;
               y3 = yholder + 2;
               y4 = yholder + 3;
      s1[xholder][yholder] = true;
      s1[xholder][y2] = true;
      s1[xholder][y3] = true;
      s1[xholder][y4] = true;
      placeflag[xholder][yholder] = true;
      placeflag[xholder][y2] = true;
      placeflag[xholder][y3] = true;
      placeflag[xholder][y4] = true;
      }

      else if(count == 2){
               y2 = yholder + 1;
               y3 = yholder + 2;
      s2[xholder][yholder] = true;
      s2[xholder][y2] = true;
      s2[xholder][y3] = true;
      placeflag[xholder][yholder] = true;
      placeflag[xholder][y2] = true;
      placeflag[xholder][y3] = true;
      }

      else if(count == 3){
               x2 = xholder + 1;
               x3 = xholder + 2;
      s3[xholder][yholder] = true;
      s3[x2][yholder] = true;
      s3[x3][yholder] = true;
      placeflag[xholder][yholder] = true;
      placeflag[x2][yholder] = true;
      placeflag[x3][yholder] = true;
      }

      else if(count == 4){
               y2 = yholder + 1;
      s4[xholder][yholder] = true;
      s4[xholder][y2] = true;
      placeflag[xholder][yholder] = true;
      placeflag[xholder][y2] = true;
      }

      else if(count == 5){
               x2 = xholder + 1;
      s5[xholder][yholder] = true;
      s5[x2][yholder] = true;
      placeflag[xholder][yholder] = true;
      placeflag[x2][yholder] = true;
      }       
  }
```

Please help me. I'm out of ideas.

**EDIT**

Forgot to mention the grid is 10x10.

[Sample of what happens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AnHjg.png)

Note: used FF ship sprites cause I haven't finished creating my own.

Comment: You have a lot of code here, and it sounds like you have multiple bugs. I would recommend that you break up this question into two or three more specific questions with only the section of code that is relevant to each problem.

Comment: Sorry. I trimmed the code. And removed the non-relevant ones. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: I'd like to see an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so it would be easier to analyse the problem.

Answer (score 0):

So it seems I just needed to take a break from coding. I managed to fix it by making separate variables for each ship so I can check each part of it accurately and avoid overloading a variable.